# Checking string for large amount of different, incremental values

Tags: java, string, loops

Currently I am checking a string for the following:

```
if(parseCommand.contains("vlan1") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1i") || parseCommand.contains("Fa0/1o") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/0") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/1") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/2") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/3") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/4") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/5") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/6") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/7") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/8") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/9") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/11") || parseCommand.contains("Gi0")) 
{
    //do things here                              
}
```

However it may contain vlan1 up to vlan4094 and i have to check for these. What is the simplest way to do this, do I have to stick it all in a for loop incrementing to 4094 I guess?

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 4094; i++)

    {
     if(parseCommand.contains("vlan"[i]))
    {  
    //do stuff here 
    }
    }

    if(other conditions from above)

    {
    //do same stuff again here
    }
```

Or else I could stick all the conditions in the for loop and do everything inside there. This all seems messy, is there a non-messy way of doing it?

Comment: a regular expression might be useful here

Comment: What's the format of the string? Is it the case that "vlan" appears multiple times, or just once?

Comment: @Beau: A regex alone can't do the parsing, but with extraction it can help a lot.  Maybe you could add an answer with how you were thinking it would work?

Comment: @Tom It will  be once, but it is possible that it may occur multiple times so I'd want a more robust way of dealing with it.

Comment: @BeauGrantham I usspose I could just change what I originally had to .matches for the vlan part and leave the rest the same, that would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I think this regex should do it:**

```
String parseCommand = "vlan4094";
if (parseCommand.matches(".*?vlan([1-3][0-9]{3}|" +
                                 "[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|" +
                                 "40(9[0-4]|[0-8][0-9])).*"))
   System.out.println("matches");
```

`[1-3][0-9]{3}` - 1000-3999
`[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` - 1-999
`9[0-4]` - 90-94
`[0-8][0-9]` - 00-89
`40(9[0-4]|[0-8][0-9])` - 4000-4094

**Something like this is probably simpler:**

```
String parseCommand = "vlan4094";
if (parseCommand.startsWith("vlan"))
{
   int v = Integer.parseInt(parseCommand.substring(4));
   if (v >= 1 && v <= 4094)
      /* do stuff */
}
```

**Suggested change:**

Replace:

```
parseCommand.contains("Fa1/0") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/1") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/2") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/3") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/4") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/5") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/6") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/7") 
|| parseCommand.contains("Fa1/8") || parseCommand.contains("Fa1/9")
```

with

```
parseCommand.matches(".*?Fa1/[0-9].*")
```

Comment: That seems reasonable thanks, good answer,  I could just change what I originally had from .contains to .matches for the vlan part and leave the rest the same, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can combie them into one boolean

```
boolean b = false;

for(int i = 1 ; i < 4094 ; i ++){
    b = b || parseCommand.contains("vlan" + i);
}
```

Then check your boolean value

Comment: I like this answer too, thanks for another way of thinking about it.

Comment: Yes this is the easiest and more understandable answer, but it is uneffective, the regular expression approach is the best.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is with "vlanXXX" you can remove the "vlan" part of the string:

```
parseCommand = parseCommand.replaceFirst("vlan", "");
```

and then cast it to int

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(parseCommand);
```

and then comparing this result with that whaat you want

```
if((value >= 1) && (value <= 4094)){....}
```

This will only work for the given case and you have to handle the case where parseCommand cannot be cast to int. And it is much more understandable than using whatever regular expresion

Comment: You may have to test if `parseCommand.contains("vlan")` before you call `replaceFirst()`, else it would also get you in in case the `parseCommand = "10"`(or any number between 1-4094). T

Comment: Thanks, another interesting answer. Do need to check a few things there!